# Restrict absolute-positioned child-div's maximum height to parent height and make its child scrollable

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a card with a header and content. The card's *maximum height* should be restricted by the parent's height. If the card can't fit, the content should be vertically scrollable.

*EDIT: To clarify, the card should shrink-wrap if the content fits on the screen.*

Here's my draft, which doesn't work:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: "100vh";
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 16px;
}

.content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="card">
    Header
    <div class="content">
      <pre>
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit. 
      </pre>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why are you using `position: absolute`?

Comment: @Paulie_D I am using `position: absolute` because there is more content, I only extracted a minimal example.

Comment: One thing is that your height value is invalid. It's `100vh`, not `"100vh"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use `flex`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: calc(100% - 32px);
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 16px;
  background: red;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.content {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="card">
    Header
    <div class="content">
      <pre>
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit. 
      </pre>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: That works, `max-height: calc...` that's the trick :-)

Answer (score 0):

Restrict the height of the card and content to 100%.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="card">
    Header
    <div class="content">
      <pre>
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit.
  This should scroll if it doesn't fit. 
      </pre>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The card should shrink-wrap if the content is not too large. With your solution, the card is always 100%.

Comment: You can't get a scroll unless you limit the height somehow and `auto` is not a defined height.